# Execute function in requested page when it is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with javascript in an ajax call

my script looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>contains large files to load</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                alert('content is completely loaded');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I reload the page it is working, but when I am dynamically loading this file with an ajax call.

my code to actually load and execute all scripts from the ajax call:

```
var tmp;
tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
tmp.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

var scripts = tmp.getElementsByTagName('script');
var scripts_length = scripts.length;

for(i = 0; i < scripts_length; ++i) {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute('src', scripts[i].getAttribute('src'));
    script_tag.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script_tag.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');
    document.body.appendChild(script_tag);
}
```

how can I let all scripts execute when someone refreshes the page and also when the content is loaded with ajax?

so: my scripts are loading but not executing because window.onload, but window.onload can't be removed because then the page refresh does not work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're lacking an *eval* function in your code, cause your described method only adds the scripts from the response to the page. You can try with the following function

```
// this function create an Array that contains the JS code of every <script> tag in parameter
// then apply the eval() to execute the code in every script collected
function parseScript(strcode) {
  var scripts = new Array();         // Array which will store the script's code

  // Strip out tags
  while(strcode.indexOf("<script") > -1 || strcode.indexOf("</script") > -1) {
    var s = strcode.indexOf("<script");
    var s_e = strcode.indexOf(">", s);
    var e = strcode.indexOf("</script", s);
    var e_e = strcode.indexOf(">", e);

    // Add to scripts array
    scripts.push(strcode.substring(s_e+1, e));
    // Strip from strcode
    strcode = strcode.substring(0, s) + strcode.substring(e_e+1);
  }

  // Loop through every script collected and eval it
  for(var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
    try {
      eval(scripts[i]);
    }
    catch(ex) {
      // do what you want here when a script fails
    }
  }
}
```

the complete article is available here http://coursesweb.net/ajax/execute-javascript-code-ajax-response_t

Answer (score 0):

attach an onload event handler to the body tag like this  or otherwise use an eventListner.and to check if when conetent is loaded by ajax.check for the onreadystatechange. for example

```
function makerequest(serverPage, objID) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(objID);
    obj.innerHTML = '<b>Loading....</b>';
    xmlhttp.open("GET", serverPage);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //perform mystunts
        }
    }
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

You can use the status code to check whatever you want to.

see Ref from w3school.com

The onreadystatechange event
When a request to a server is sent, we want to perform some actions based on the response.

The onreadystatechange event is triggered every time the readyState changes.

The readyState property holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest.

Three important properties of the XMLHttpRequest object:

onreadystatechange  Stores a function (or the name of a function) to be called automatically each time the readyState property changes
readyState  Holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest. Changes from 0 to 4: 
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready
status  200: "OK"
404: Page not found